# How to analyze Apex CPU consumption

Tags: debugging, cpulimit, debug-logs

Is there a tool or a recommended approach to analyzing Apex CPU consumption based on a debug log?

For example, consider the log entries below.

```
18:47:41.12 (7012039114)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q460000001BZF|ContactTrigger on Contact trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/ContactTrigger
18:47:49.44 (15513727451)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ContactTrigger on Contact trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/ContactTrigger
```

I would want to quickly see that **8.5 sec** (15,513,727,451 ns - 7,012,039,114 ns) was expended in this one trigger execution.

Comment: Is the [Limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) an option (specifically `Limits.getCpuTime()`)?

Comment: Are you familiar / aware of the various [debug perspectives available in the Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_perspectives_working.htm&type=5) for getting information out of the logs? You are probably most interested in viewing the Analysis perspective to get the information you're seeking.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @MarkPond! I'm reviewing this data now.

Comment: @MarkPond the link you gave was spot-on! If you can post that as an answer I'd love to mark this solution as the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various debug perspectives available in the Developer Console for getting information out of the logs? You are probably most interested in viewing the Analysis perspective to get the information you're seeking.

[image: Developer Console Log Inspector]

[Developer Console - Managing Perspectives in the Log Inspector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_perspectives_working.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you're open to something commercial, but Illuminated Cloud's [Log Analyzer](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/announcements/2074releasenotes) has specialized views for profiling various resources including CPU time, heap, SOQL queries and DML, etc.

Here's a video demonstrating its features:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1_az389jgk

and here's a pic showing the type of drill-down analysis it provides:

[image: Illuminated Cloud 2 Log Analyzer]

Comment: I should have watched this months ago :-(; +1 for the video. Does it help differentiate hotspots by distinguishing between Apex , Process Builder, and Flow?

Comment: Only in the sense that those are represented by distinct code units and would roll up independently.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @ScottWells! While I've lost my edge with the IntelliJ IDE, I appreciate knowing that there's a commercial alternative to the standard tool set.

Comment: I didn't know log analyzer could be used for this, thanks! @ScottWells

Answer (score 1):

[Apex log analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=financialforce.lana) which is a VSCode plugin, is a great tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

@ronnie777 your answer for the Apex Log Analyzer is going to be a game changer for me, thank you!

Trying to parse through 84k lines in the log just wasn't going to happen and this UI is fantastic to see what was eating up CPU time:
[image: apex log analyzer screenshot sorted by CPU time]