# Apex callout, need to iterate through pages

Tags: apex, callout

I am new to apex.
I am making an api call from salesforce to get contacts from another application.

I am receiving contacts but in pages, I need to parse the response and make a call again to get the next page. What am I doing wrong that I get

> APEX CPU Execution time limit exceeded

The response I get in my first call is a list of contacts and

```
pages": {
        "type": "pages",
        "next": {
            "page": 42,
            "starting_after": "WzE2NjQ0MjUzM"
        },
        "page": 41,
        "per_page": 150,
        "total_pages": 56
    }
```

I need to send it this way

```
{
 "query":  {
    "field": "last_seen_at",
    "operator": ">",
    "value": "1646149510"
  },
  "pagination": {
    "per_page": 5,
    "starting_after": "1HaSB+xrOyyMXAkS"
  } 
}
```

```java
Http h = new Http();

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search/');
req.setMethod('POST');
String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + '<redacted>';
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);  
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Intercom-Version', '2.6');

Map<String, Object> m1 = new Map<String, Object> { 
   'value' => '1646149510',
   'operator' => '>', 
   'field' => 'last_seen_at'
};

String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> {'query' => m1}
);
   
req.setBody(jsonBody);
   
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
List<Object> listObject = (List<Object>)results.get('data');
Map<String, Object>  pagesObject, NextpagesObject;

pagesObject = (Map<String, Object>)(results.get('pages'));
NextpagesObject = (Map<String, Object>)(pagesObject.get('next'));

while(NextpagesObject != null){
    Integer page = Integer.valueOf(NextpagesObject.get('page'));
    String starting_after = String.valueOf(NextpagesObject.get('starting_after'));
    
    Http h2 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
    req2.setEndpoint('https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search/');
    req2.setMethod('POST');
    String authorizationHeader2 = 'Bearer ' + '<redacted 2>';
    req2.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader2);  
    req2.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req2.setHeader('Intercom-Version', '2.6');
      
    Map<String, Object> m2 = new Map<String, Object> { 
       'value' => '1646149510',
       'operator' => '>', 
       'field' => 'last_seen_at'
    };
                   
    Map<String, Object> m3 = new Map<String, Object> {
        'per_page' => page,
        'starting_after' => starting_after
    } ;

    String jsonBody2 = JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> {
             'query' => m2,
             'pagination' => m3
        }
    );

    req2.setBody(jsonBody2);
    HttpResponse res2 = h.send(req2);
    Map<String, Object> results2 = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    listObject = (List<Object>)(results2.get('data'));
    pagesObject  = (Map<String, Object>)(results2.get('pages'));
    NextpagesObject = (Map<String, Object>)(pagesObject.get('next'));
}
```

Comment: Is this a continuation of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388953/create-a-request-in-apex-need-help-in-using-map-or-list ?

Comment: Also, you should never post credentials publically. I've removed them, but bots scrape sites for information like this. If those were really the entirety of your credentials, they are compromised and you need to get new ones.

Comment: @Derek F Thanks so much. Please help me

Comment: Only you can answer this question. Have you tried https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287717/how-to-analyze-apex-cpu-consumption